# glsl passing data array from vertex to tessellation control shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

I am trying to pass a vec3 array from vertex shader to tessellation shader.

passing just one value works fine, but how to pass an array?

**Vertex shader**

```
#version 430
out vec3 data; //working!
out vec3 dataArray[2];
void main()
{
    gl_position = vec4(0,0,0,0);
    data = vec3(1,2,3);
    dataArray[0] = vec3(1,2,3);
    dataArray[1] = vec3(4,5,6);
}
```

**tessellation controll shader**

```
#version 430
layout (vertices = 3) out;

in vec3 data[]; //working!
in vec3 dataArray[2][]; // how to do this?

void main()
{
    ...
}
```

The error message is: error C7618: OpenGL/ES does not allow input array declarations with size not equal to gl_MaxPatchVertices

I also tried

```
in vec3 dataArray[2][gl_MaxPatchVertices]
```

But this also doesn't work.

Comment: how can I get the value of gl_MaxPatchVertices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> in vec3 dataArray[2][]; // how to do this?
> ```

[Arrays of arrays in GLSL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Arrays_of_arrays) work differently than you might expect. The array indices are read left-to-right. For example, `vec2 var[2][3]` is a 2-element array of 3-element arrays of `vec2`s.

What you want is an "unsized array of 2 element arrays of `vec3`". To do that, you need `in vec3 dataArray[][2];`.

Alternatively, you can declare the main type next to the type name and the array aggregation beside the variable name: `in vec3[2] dataArray[];`. GLSL allows this kind of split declaration style, where the array sizes on the type happen before the array sizes on the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Change the output of the vertex shader to

```
out vec3[2] dataArray;
```

and the input to the tessellation control shader as

```
in vec3[2] dataArray[];
```

That should work. Alternatively you could also define the type of dataArray as a struct.